# Imagebutton showing id of imagebutton but not image

Tags: android, eclipse, imagebutton

I am trying to display an image on an imagebutton.  I have a source image specified without errors, but in the graphical layout I see the imagebutton's id instead of its source.

Here is the xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="196dp" >

    <imageTruck
        android:id="@+id/truck"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/img_4932_filtered"
        android:onClick="imageChangerTruck" />

    <imageCar
        android:id="@+id/car"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/img_3972_filtered"
        android:onClick="imageChangerCar" />

    <imageBoat
        android:id="@+id/boat"
        android:layout_width="57dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/img_6993_filtered"
        android:onClick="imageChangerBoat" />

    <imageBus
        android:id="@+id/bus"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/img_3165"
        android:onClick="imageChangerBus" />

    <imageMotorcycle
        android:id="@+id/motorcycle"
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/img_0081"
        android:onClick="imageChangerMotorcycle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code was working just fine until I put it into a linear layout.  There are no error messages that show up, but the application crashes every time I run it.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `<imageMotorcycle>` tag it shouldn't be `<imageButton>` tag? and for every other imagebuttons?